# Take 4 columns of identical data from 2 sheets with 2 columns of unique, sort by common

Tags: excel, sorting

I've tried several VLookup strings and couldn't get it. Apologize in advance if this has been covered but spent hour and half looking/trying.

I have 2 inventory sheets. Columns 1-2 are identical on each (part #, Description). Column 3 has the inventory count for each period. I'd like to put them on one sheet with data lining up across rows. Problem is the #s aren't in same order on each sheet. Tried copy/paste and sort by Part#, then Part # but they don't match for some reason. Thank you so much. Chris.

```
Part #  Description     Count Part #    Description     Count
29169   SERIAL NUMBERL  300   50001E    Impulse Finger  7,234
50010   Air Reject Bae  45    72000-S   Chromax HD Ill  28
```

Comment: I'm sorry, partner, having much difficulty due to ignorance. Here's what I see vs like to see.

Answer (score 0):

Name your value ranges as "Inventory1" and "Inventory2"

Go to Data>From Other Sources>From Microsoft Query

Then, select excel files, navigate to your workbook, and select both your ranges into the selection box.

Go into your Microsoft Query, and click the SQL button.

```
Select Inventory1.PartNum, Inventory1.Description, Inventory1.Count 
FROM C:\$\Inventory1 C:\$\Inventory1
UNION ALL
Select Inventory2.PartNum, Inventory2.Description, Inventory2.Count
FROM C:\$\Inventory2 C:\$\Inventory2
```

Basically, this query will join your two ranges on top of each other based on the columns in the respective query (i.e: Partnum on Partnum).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]